# App throws CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate using PFX generated from Certbot on Linux

Tags: c#, mono, x509certificate2

We're using the pfx file in a Hololens2 app that is using the [WebRTC](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC) library (which wasn't deprecated at the time the application was created). The application was working, but the cert expired and that dev is no longer with us, so without making any changes to the source code, I'm just trying to get a cert that works with it.

I have a linux server that has an ssl that was created using Certbot. I followed the instructions on [Certbot's site](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntufocal) to create the certificate.

There's a ton of support using openssl to generate the pfx file using the pem files that are available on my server.

I'm using the following files:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/<myurl>/privkey.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/<myurl>/cert.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/<myurl>/fullchain.pem
```

Another dev we worked with left documentation that he used Let's Encrypt on a linux server and used these files with the following command to create the pfx file we use for websocket connections:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile fullchain.pem -export -out app.pfx
```

I then copy the generated pfx file from the linux machine into a Unity project on my Windows 10 machine.

In C# when I run this line of code it returns the previously specified exception:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path_to_pfx, "MyPassword");
```

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x0003b] in <6a66fe237d4242c9924192d3c28dd540>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00322] in <6a66fe237d4242c9924192d3c28dd540>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <6a66fe237d4242c9924192d3c28dd540>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00041] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00005] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00007] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password) [0x00011] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at WebSocketSignaler.BeginSharing () [0x0003c] in D:\Projects\SKIRUN\simon-hl\Simon\Assets\Scripts\WebRTC\WebSocketSignaler.cs:87 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
WebSocketSignaler:BeginSharing () (at Assets/Scripts/WebRTC/WebSocketSignaler.cs:125)
RTCServer:BeginSharing () (at Assets/Scripts/WebRTC/RTCServer.cs:120)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke ()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.SpeechInputHandler:Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler.OnSpeechKeywordRecognized (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.SpeechEventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/SDK/Features/Input/Handlers/SpeechInputHandler.cs:127)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem/<>c:<.cctor>b__244_38 (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler,UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Services/InputSystem/MixedRealityInputSystem.cs:1824)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseEventSystem:HandleEvent<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData,UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents/EventFunction`1<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Core/Services/BaseEventSystem.cs:118)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:DispatchEventToGlobalListeners<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler> (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.BaseInputEventData,UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents/EventFunction`1<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Services/InputSystem/MixedRealityInputSystem.cs:600)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:HandleEvent<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData,UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents/EventFunction`1<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealitySpeechHandler>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Services/InputSystem/MixedRealityInputSystem.cs:448)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:RaiseSpeechCommandRecognized (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityInputSource,Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.RecognitionConfidenceLevel,System.TimeSpan,System.DateTime,Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.SpeechCommands) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Services/InputSystem/MixedRealityInputSystem.cs:1860)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Windows.Input.WindowsSpeechInputProvider:OnPhraseRecognized (UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel,System.TimeSpan,System.DateTime,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Providers/Windows/WindowsSpeechInputProvider.cs:253)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Windows.Input.WindowsSpeechInputProvider:KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized (UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognizedEventArgs) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@db8f9c58e4f2-1676478042988/Providers/Windows/WindowsSpeechInputProvider.cs:238)
UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognizer:InvokePhraseRecognizedEvent (string,UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel,UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.SemanticMeaning[],long,long)
```

I've also tried loading the cert in like so:

```
byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(path_to_pfx);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(contents, "MyPassword");
```

Both yield the same excpetion.

I'm using Unity 2020.3.28f1 (Can't upgrade for reasons I won't get into) which uses Mono version 5.11.0.

I've tried using openssl on my Windows machine to generate the pfx file and have tried different variations of the command with different files, all of which yield the same result.

I'd like to note, that before I went the Let's Encrypt route, we purchased an SSL Cert from GoDaddy, I spun up a Windows 2016 Server VM, created a Certificate request, submitted it to GoDaddy, waited for a new SSL to be generated, then downloaded the certs for IIS and followed GoDaddy's instructions for installing it on the server. I was then able to export a pfx file and use that and it didn't throw the error. But we ran into other issues which I won't get into.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I've been at this for too long and I'm probably too close to see the glaring issue one of you is bound to point out.

Comment: Ensure that your PFX file is a pure binary data, not PEM or base64.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I've double checked and confirmed it's binary data. I can double click it an install the certificate on my machine, so it's a valid certificate, but Mono just doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: It's probably that your PFX is using options that are too new for the flavor of Mono you're using.  To use the old defaults, you can specify `-macalg SHA1 -certpbe RC2-40 -keypbe 3DES` on your `openssl pkcs12` command.

Comment: When I try to use RC2-40 it tells me `Unknown PBE algorithm RC2-40`. I tried using `-macalg SHA1 -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES` and was met with the same exception.